# How to tell apache to prepend to each html page login.php?

Tags: php, apache

I have a static web pages protected by *apache basic auth*. It is not allowing users to logout.

I would like to protect all pages using simple database and cookie based authorization using php sessions and keep apache basic auth as well.

So to do that I need to add to each html file  login.php to manage login/logout process.

How to configure apache to add th following text to each html file `<  ?php include login.php? >`

The reason to do this using apache that I dont  want to touch or add any code to the plain html files,the editors are generating only htmls.

Thank you beforehand

Arman

**EDIT:**

using Marks suggestion solves my problem, in .htaccess file:

```
# HTACCESS CODE BEGIN
php_value auto_prepend_file "full_path_to_the_include_directory/prepend.php"
php_value auto_append_file "full_path_to_the_file_containing_your_analytics_code"
# HTACCESS CODE ENDS
```

taken from: [weberdev](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4922.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [auto_prepend_file](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)=login.php in your php.ini file, or you can set the auto_prepend_file value as a directive in .htaccess or your hosts section of httpd.conf

Comment: Thank you this prevents me to change the original files.